# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Cookie Authentication without identity not directing to LoginPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core

Moved from ASP.NET Core 1.1 to 2.0 and having issues with cookie authentication.

The application will not follow the `LoginPath` and goes directly to the `AccessDeniedPath`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
        });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(Constants.CONST_POLICY_SUPERADMIN, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.CONST_ROLE_SUPERADMIN));
        options.AddPolicy(Constants.CONST_POLICY_ADMIN, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.CONST_ROLE_ADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_SUPERADMIN));
        options.AddPolicy(Constants.CONST_POLICY_DIR, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.CONST_ROLE_ADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_SUPERADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_DIR));
        options.AddPolicy(Constants.CONST_POLICY_HoD, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.CONST_ROLE_ADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_SUPERADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_DIR, Constants.CONST_ROLE_HoD));
        options.AddPolicy(Constants.CONST_POLICY_STAFF, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.CONST_ROLE_ADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_SUPERADMIN, Constants.CONST_ROLE_DIR, Constants.CONST_ROLE_HoD, Constants.CONST_ROLE_STAFF));
    });
}
```

This does not redirect to the login method at all. While testing I changed the `AccessDeniedPath` to point at the Login method, and it logs the user in fine.

Completely stumped as to why the `LoginPath` doesn't direct to the `Login` method.

Comment: I tried to create `asp.net core 2.0` app from scratch and the redirectoin worked.  It looks like you have some additional configuration.

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add [Authorize] to the controller(s) you wish to force redirect from.

e.g.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

 [Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ ....
```